# R: add custom legend to ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, ggtext

I have the following plot:

[image]

And would like to add a legend as follows:
[image]

This is the code I used to generate the plot:

```r
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

blue <- "#4472C4"
green <- "#548235"
red <- "#C55A11"
redblood <- "#C00000"

DT <- data.table(student = c("Jane", "Sam", "Tim", "Kate", "Claire"),
                 grade = c(10, 14, 8, 9, 19))

b0 <- 13

DT[, gradeHat := b0]
DT[, e := grade - gradeHat]
DT[, SS := sum(e**2)]

DT[, id := 1:nrow(DT)]
DT[, xmin := id]
DT[, xmax := id + abs(e)/20*3]
DT[, ymin := min(grade, gradeHat), id]
DT[, ymax := max(grade, gradeHat), id]
DT[, student := factor(student, levels = student)]

gg <- ggplot(DT) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = student, xend = student, y = grade, yend = gradeHat),
               color = redblood, size = 1.3) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax),
            fill = redblood, alpha = .4) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = b0, color = green, alpha = .7, size = 1, linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_point(aes(student, grade), color = blue, size = 4) +
  geom_point(aes(student, gradeHat), color = green, size = 4) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 0:20, limits = c(0, 20)) +
  coord_fixed(.15) +
  theme_classic()

plot(gg)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a full solution for your problem ... but the best I could come up with at the moment:

1. To get a legend in ggplot you have to map on aesthetics, i.e. instead of setting colors as arguments you have to map on `color` or `fill` inside `aes()`. To this end you can make use of placeholders or labels, e.g. `fill="SS"` in `geom_rect`.
2. To get the colors right you can make use of `scale_color/fill_manual`. Using the labels makes it easy to assign the right colors.
3. Next, to get the styling of the legend right you can make use of `guide_legend` and its argument `override.aes` to set the shapes and linetypes for the color legend.
4. By default there is some spacing between the `color` and `fill` legend, which however can be removed in `theme()` via `legend.spacing` and `legend.margin`.
5. Final part is to color the legend labels. This could be achieved via the `ggtext` package which via theme option `legend.text = element_markdown()` allows to style the legend entries using HTML and CSS.

Unfortunately I was not able to figure out how to get the wide hat on your `gradeHat`.

```r
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

blue <- "#4472C4"
green <- "#548235"
red <- "#C55A11"
redblood <- "#C00000"

DT <- data.table(student = c("Jane", "Sam", "Tim", "Kate", "Claire"),
                 grade = c(10, 14, 8, 9, 19))

b0 <- 13

DT[, gradeHat := b0]
DT[, e := grade - gradeHat]
DT[, SS := sum(e**2)]

DT[, id := 1:nrow(DT)]
DT[, xmin := id]
DT[, xmax := id + abs(e)/20*3]
DT[, ymin := min(grade, gradeHat), id]
DT[, ymax := max(grade, gradeHat), id]
DT[, student := factor(student, levels = student)]

ggplot(DT) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = student, xend = student, y = grade, yend = gradeHat, color = "error"),
               , size = 1.3) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax, fill = "SS"), alpha = .4) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = b0, color = green, alpha = .7, size = 1, linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_point(aes(student, grade, color = "grade"), size = 4) +
  geom_point(aes(student, gradeHat, color = "gradeHat"), size = 4) +
  scale_color_manual(breaks = c("grade", "gradeHat", "error"), 
                     values = c(grade = blue, gradeHat = green, error = red),
                     labels = c(grade = glue::glue("<span style = 'color: {blue};'>grade</span>"),
                                gradeHat = glue::glue("<span style = 'color: {green};'>gradeHat</span>"), 
                                error = glue::glue("<span style = 'color: {red};'>error</span>"))) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(SS = redblood), labels = c(SS = glue::glue("<span style = 'color: #C0000066; '>SS</span>"))) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(order = 1, override.aes = list(shape = c(16, 16, NA), linetype = c("blank", "dashed", "solid")))) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 0:20, limits = c(0, 20)) +
  coord_fixed(.15) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", 
        legend.spacing = unit(0, "pt"), 
        legend.margin = margin(r = 0, l = 0),
        legend.text = ggtext::element_markdown()) +
  labs(color = NULL, fill = NULL)
```

[image]

Comment: Ha ha! 2 seconds apart! Slightly different methods though, so we're all good!

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's (just about) possible:

```r
gg <- ggplot(DT) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = student, xend = student, y = grade, yend = gradeHat,
               color = "Error"), size = 1.3) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax, fill = "SS"),
            alpha = .4) +
  geom_hline(aes(alpha = "Grade", yintercept = 13), linetype = 2,
             color = green, size = 1, key_glyph = "pointrange") +
  geom_point(aes(student, grade, shape = "Grade"), color = blue, size = 4) +
  geom_point(aes(student, gradeHat), color = green, size = 4)  +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 0:20, limits = c(0, 20)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = 19, name = NULL, guide = guide_legend(order = 1)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = redblood, name = NULL, 
                     guide = guide_legend(order = 3)) +
  scale_alpha_manual(breaks = "Grade", values = 1,
                    guide = guide_legend(order = 2,
                                         override.aes = list(color = green)),
                    name = "") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = redblood, name = NULL) +
  coord_fixed(.15) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.key.width = unit(20, "points")) 

plot(gg)
```

[image]